# Prolog binary tree height and balance check

Tags: prolog

I have a forest of binary trees represented like this:

```
node(a). node(b). node(c). node(d). node(e). 
node(f). node(g). node(h). 
node(i).
node(j). node(k). node(l).

edge(a,b). edge(a,c). edge(b,d). 
edge(f,g). edge(f,h). 
edge(j,k). edge(k,l).
```

And I have some functions:

```
isLeaf(X):- node(X), \+ edge(X, _).
isRoot(X):- node(X), \+ edge(_, X).
```

But I got stuck at height and balance.
For height I tried first to see the heights through all the paths:

```
height(X, H):- edge(X, Y), height(Y, N1), N1 is H + 1.
isBalanced(X):- edge(X, Y), edge(X, Z), Y \= Z isBalanced(Y), isBalanced(Z).
```

Comment: How exactly do you define "balanced"? I don't see a definition (in words or in code) of what tree would qualify as balanced. Also, both `height/2` and `isBalanced/2` are clear cases of infinite recursion (without commenting on the other errors).